# How could I communicate with an RS232 device in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, serial-port, foundation, serial-communication

I'm trying to write a command-line, Foundation Objective-C program and I need to communicate to an RS232 serial device.

Any ideas on how to do this?

EDIT - This is *NOT* for iPhone! This is a DESKTOP APPLICATION.

Answer (score 4):

I'm assuming you are using an RS-232/USB adapter. If I were doing it, I'd figure out which device it shows up on, and just open it using the open("/dev/ttyS0", etc) function. You can then wrap up the file descriptor and the access functions in an object.

Here is a page on playing with serial ports in POSIX environments:
http://www.easysw.com/~mike/serial/serial.html

Comment: Where would I find a manual for this function? Sorry, I'm JUST getting started in this language.

Comment: Also, how might I configure baud, tx/rx blocking, etc?

Comment: The page I linked to should give you that info and some example code. For the open() syscall fire up Terminal and just type "man 2 open".

Answer (score 0):

I used so-called "Serial Device Server" from moxa and it worked like a charm.

Advantages over USB-Serial converter:

- The device can be integrated anywhere in the network
- on application side it is just well-documented network programming

Device Server in general allow you to connect to a serial device by using networks like [LAN](http://www.moxa.com/product/NPort_5100A.htm) or [WiFi](http://www.moxa.com/product/NPort_W2150A_W2250A.htm).

Software side it would be quite easy network/socket programming, like:

(Using [GCDAsyncSocket](https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaAsyncSocket))

Preparing data

```
static u_int8_t cmd1[] = { 0x1a, 0x73, 0x10 }; //defined by the serial device's protocol
static u_int8_t cmd2[] = { 0x1b, 0x51, 0x01 };

self.data = [NSMutableData dataWithBytes:&cmd1 length:sizeof(cmd1)];
[self.data appendData:[string dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[self.data appendBytes:&cmd2 length:sizeof(cmd2)];
```

sending data

```
-(IBAction)buttonAction:(id)sender
{
    NSError *error = nil;
    [self.socket connectToHost:@"192.168.1.9" onPort:1234 withTimeout:-1 error:&error];
    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"error: %@", error);
    }
}


-(void)socket:(GCDAsyncSocket *)sock didConnectToHost:(NSString *)host port:(uint16_t)port
{
    [self.socket writeData:self.data withTimeout:-1 tag:23];
}
```